# Color Change with PDF on iDevices

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, color-conversion, iphone, pantone

I was wondering if someone had a solution to keep PMS colors the right color when exporting a PDF from Adobe Illustrator. I have been having issues when i create a document using specific PMS colors which will print fine but when emailed and opened on an iDevice or non adobe reader, they change to be a more vibrant color. i have recently switched to use inDesign and that has since fixed the problem but we have some old files that are PDFs from illustrator that have this weird problem. any help would be appreciate.

i do save as PDF > illustrator default > output to destination > us web swop v2 > no compression.

Comment: *Anything* other than and Adobe product will almost * always* show spot colors incorrectly. Realize that only professionals are using Pantone colors... the average iOS user doesn't know or care about spot colors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any iDevices application doing proper color management. So, there is not much you can do about it.